# Define starting day in week using hour and not just date

Tags: python, datetime, offset, datetime-format, dayofweek

I need to define a "long" week by hour in a day.

The week will start on Tuesday at 12AM and will end on next Tuesday at 6AM.

The next week will do an overlap (again starting from Tuesday at 12AM and so on).

Can this be done with `isocalendar` or `strftime`?

Comment: What trouble are you having?

Comment: If your weeks overlap by 6 hours, how do you decide which week a time early Tuesday morning falls in?

Comment: >if your weeks overlap by 6 hours, how do you decide which week a time early Tuesday morning falls in?                                                Great question. I will assign certain hours to both weeks. Let's make it easier - suppose I want a week that starts on 6:22AM every Tuesday and ends on 6:22AM a week afterwards, so constant shifts, 24x7 hours-coverage. How do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: @PeterWood Hi Peter, I need to give a solution to overlapping weeks - one way to do that is to create two divisions into shifted weeks and then to adjust duplicated dates. But I don't know how to make a (hours/minutes) shift in per-week division. After that, adjusting might be messy but bearable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta), which is part of the standard [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) library:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

Given a starting date:

```
>>> start = datetime(year=2015, month=5, day=4, hour=0)
>>> start
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 4, 0, 0)
```

You can use `timedelta` to store the difference between dates:

```
>>> long_week = timedelta(weeks=1, hours=6)
```

Add the delta to the start date:

```
>>> end = start + long_week
>>> end
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 11, 6, 0)
```